# Google drive modifiedTime changes after update response

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I updated a file using the client API:

```
FilesResource.UpdateMediaUpload request;
request = Service.Files.Update(new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File(), id, stream);
request.Upload();

var Modified = request.ResponseBody.ModifiedTime;
```

I then requested for the same file after:

```
var modified = Service.Files.Get(id).Execute().ModifiedTime
```

These dates are milliseconds out of sync, i.e.:

modified.ticks = 636284845226980000

Modified.ticks = 636284845229162448

Modified.time - modified.time = 218ms

Why is this happening, and how can I rectify this?

Comment: it is literally the code in the question, I update, and then right after, I "get". The times are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because the file meta data is being updated asynchronously and there is nothing you can do to rectify it because it isn't a fault.

If you explain why this causes you a problem, there may be an alternative approach. Eg:-

1. Use the revisions feed
2. Use the changes feed
3. For non-Google files, you can use the md5sum
4. If you are happy to use the v2 API, you can
   use etag
5. Use the Properties feature to "tag" the file manually with an increment or timestamp

Comment: would the "modifiedByMeTime" help?

Comment: Can you explain why are you tracking it and why does a 218ms discrepancy affect you? Like I said, this is NOT an issue and is NOT going to be "fixed" so if you explain what you are trying to do, maybe we can suggest some alternatives.

Comment: I'm checking whether the file's been updating, so I can download it.

Comment: Maybe I should change to using the changes api, but will that work for the appDataFolder

Comment: I don't see the change, what modifiedTime are you seeing for your answer?

Comment: What do you mean non-google files? I'm going to try using the changes for, for a json file

Comment: Google files eg. Sheets, Slides, Documents, etc with a mime-type of application/vnd.google-apps-xxxxxxxx