# Latency From Google Drive v3's modifiedTime attribute

Tags: google-drive-api

To avoid updating a Google Spreadsheet (via Sheets v4 API) if it's unchanged, I maintain a cache of the spreadsheet's data. I use the Google Drive v3 API's [modifiedTime property](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) to establish whether or not my cache is out of date.

I've noticed, though, that `modifiedTime` doesn't update immediately after something (be it an API call or a user in the web interface) actually modifies the spreadsheet. It often takes several *minutes*. That makes the cache data somewhat unreliable (because it might be a minute or two out of date, but the latency means I can't know that right now).

Am I missing something? If not, is there another way to get this information *without* latency?

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562875/google-drive-modifiedtime-changes-after-update-response) may be partially responsive but I'm not sure where to go with it.

Comment: why arent you using push notifications? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/change-overview

Comment: Because I prefer to avoid setting up a web server for the application in question. I just want the latest modification time of the resource, and it’s better if that information isn’t minutes out of date.

Comment: please edit your question and include enough code so that i can test it

Comment: If the update is always made via the web interface, you could use `Google Apps Script` and use an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onedit) trigger to track updates, get the current time everytime the spreadsheet gets updated and send that time to your application. Would that be a valid workaround?